# Google spreadsheets OnEdit event is not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have developed some code in the onEdit function, and it's working fine while I am on the develeopment mode, however when I make a deployment and add a test deployment for a sheet the OnEdit event is not being triggered. Is there any option I need to enable to make it work?

Comment: I don't understand why you would make a deployment for an onEdit script

Comment: I am developing an add on and I want to deploy the whole addon including the OnEdit Script as there are some features depends on it

Comment: You may need to make it an installable trigger because simple triggers can not do things that require permission.